# Zscaler/SSL inspection proxy solution for IoT Edge

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Does Azure IoT Edge works with Zscaler proxy AND SSL inspection

Indeed, we need to check header information from IoT Edge for security reason which require to decrypt .
IoT Edge run in CentOS or Ubuntu ESX VM and Zscaler certificat can be uploaded in the OS file system

regards

Answer (score 1):

You will need the Zscaler root certificate added to list of root certificates that are trusted by OpenSSL in both the edgeAgent and edgeHub modules. Without that the TLS negotiation will fail with not trusting the certificate chain from any server that they attempt to negotiation a TLS connection with. I have done this. It will work.

Comment: [How to add ZScaler certificate to edgeHub and edgeAgent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71871323/how-to-add-zscaler-certificate-to-edgehub-and-edgeagent)

Comment: I added a more detailed answer in the question referenced above.